# Error : Memory limit has been reached on product image upload after server migration - magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

After migrating my Magento site to a new server (CentOS 6 ) I can't update or upload new images to any of my products. its showing Memory limit has been reached while uploading any images.

logs :

```
2016-02-04T07:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /var/www/vhosts/luxyprints.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
2016-02-04T07:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
2016-02-04T07:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98
2016-02-04T07:24:35+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 100
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6q5z.png]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase de memory limit of your php:

Open *`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`* in a text editor

Change memory_limit to:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

And you can check creating a file info.php

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

**Check the variable: memory limit**

Comment: yes i changed it to memory_limit = 768M. still no luck